# What is the difference between idn and idn2?

Tags: domain

what is the difference between [idn](https://wiki.debian.org/IDN) and [idn2](https://packages.debian.org/idn2)? (why two that do almost the same. why the output is different. Which one should be used)

infile:

```
Amazon.com
ama--zon.com
a--mazon.com
--amazon.com
amazon--.com
amazon-.com

cat infile | idn
Amazon.com
ama--zon.com
a--mazon.com
--amazon.com
amazon--.com
amazon-.com

cat infile | idn2
amazon.com
ama--zon.com
a--mazon.com
idn2: toAscii: string start/ends with forbidden hyphen
```

(for 3 last entry)

THK

**Update:** This is the answer what i'm looking for. Thanks. Vote close.

[GNU IDN Library - Libidn](https://www.gnu.org/software/libidn/)
Please be aware that GNU libidn2 is the successor of GNU libidn. It comes with IDNA 2008 and TR46 implementation and also provides a compatibility layer for GNU libidn.

Comment: I haven't used either tool, but the 2nd is better: the labels in domain names cannot start or end with a `-`. Also, the domain names have to be converted to lowercase before being converted to idns.

Comment: @mosvy I know that. It is only an example to show differences and know why both show different results (no matter what the result). I honestly don't know what the difference between them is. And it is what I want to know

Comment: @JeffSchaller No matter what the result. What I want to know what is the difference between idn and idn2 and which one should i use and why. That's it.

Comment: One of them is certainly wrong, they other _may_ be wrong. Now you know the difference.

Comment: "Also, the domain names have to be converted to lowercase before being converted to idns. " This was true in IDNA2003 but is not anymore in IDNA2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you call "IDN" is IDNA2003, and "IDN2" is IDNA2008 (specified in 2010).

There are differences between the two, and "it's complicated". You don't say a lot about your use case or constraints, so no points going in depth as there are lots of other resources. One of the major difference though is about some characters and their mapping, as well as handling of uppercases.

Also, none of the name you chose are relevant for IDNA as IDNA purpose is to handle names in the DNS using other characters than US-ASCII.
Like the German eszett: ß

So witness the following:

```
$ idn straße.de
strasse.de
$ idn2 straße.de
xn--strae-oqa.de
```

Yes, this character is one of the important differences between the two standards.

More importantly, on "which to choose". It is not for you to choose, it depends on the registry where the domains are. Today (in 2023) all registries should be using IDNA2008 (yet I can't prove as a fact that none exist still using IDNA2003) BUT they also have to keep forward compatibility if they started accepting IDNs before ~2010, so they may have domains registered that follow IDNA2003 and are invalid under IDNA2008, so that if they are deleted, noone would be able to register them again at that registry. Then you have other registries not following IDNA at all and hence allowing all sorts of other cases, like emojis.

As for your specific example on `amazon-.com`, note that per DNS rules (so unrelated to IDNs per se), no labels can start or end with an hyphen. So this name will never be valid.